# ST_ClusterDBSCAN in PostGIS gives me 0 for the cluster ID

Tags: postgis, clustering, spatial-cluster

I am trying to cluster latitudes and longitudes from a dataset containing locations in Germany (n=52612, about 9000 without duplicates).
I am running the DBSCAN algorithm, but for none of the parameter values I have tried, I am getting any clusters- the cluster ID is 0 for all rows (I have also tried all coordinates vs. only unique ones).
I did a similar exercise with Python's DBSCAN in sklearn and got some clusters there for a broad range of parameter values.
What is wrong here?

eps = 20000 corresponds to 20km, is that correct?
Anyway, I don't get any results irrespective of the eps-value

```
--add geometry
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN geom GEOMETRY;
UPDATE table SET geom = (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng,lat),4326)) ;
CREATE INDEX gix ON table USING GIST (geom);
--cluster
SELECT  *, ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom::geometry, eps := 20000, minpoints := 100) over () AS cluster_id
FROM table
WHERE year = 2010
and country = 'Germany'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

20000 is most probably in degrees - which is why all of your geometries are in cluster 0 (if it was failing to cluster they would be in NULL). You need to convert your data to be in metres by reprojecting into a local projection (SRID). For example [EPSG:5243](https://epsg.io/5243) would work, so something like:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN geom_m GEOMETRY;
UPDATE table SET geom_m = ST_TRANSFORM(geom, 5243) ;
CREATE INDEX gix_m ON table USING GIST (geom_m);
```

Comment: i am quite a gis noob, but is there any projection that I can transform to, so that I can get a proper result for points that are spread all over the world?
I use the data-type geography for my distance calculations (ST_distance) which works fine. But as ST_ClusterDBSCAN does not allow geometries, how can I archive that for a world-wide dataset?