# ClusterDBSCAN eps unit is meter or degrees if SRID is 4326

Tags: postgis, spatial-cluster

My SRID is 4326 for the points_geom column. Here is my code:

```
SELECT row_id, ST_ClusterDBSCAN(points_geom, eps := 100, minPoints := 5)
  OVER(ORDER BY row_id) AS cluster_id FROM subset_cr
```

Am I correct in assuming eps = 100 means 100 metres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.** You are looking at an `eps` distance of 100 *degrees*!

`ST_ClusterDBSCAN` currently has no signature accepting a `GEOGRAPHY`, so your only option is to `ST_Transform` your input `GEOMETRY`s to a suitable projection defining *meter* as its primary unit of measure.

---

Except for the results of distance functions, where the measurement unit of the returned value can depend on either parameters or types, all functions in the PostGIS environment return **the same *unit of measurement* specified in the Coordinate Reference System of the input geometry values**!

Comment: so how do I transform it to meters? can you please let me know

Comment: but the unit of measurement of SRID 4326 IS meters right?

Comment: No, it is *degree*, `EPSG:4326` is a geographic refrence system. See my update; you will have to find a suitable projection for your area of interest that uses *meter*!

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/304222/211549 - this would work, sure. But is there a way to accomplish this for someone who does not have write privileges in the db?

Comment: Also, if I ask the db admin to change the SRID just for my use case, all the existing queries which use that column will go haywire I presume!

Comment: You can transform at query time, i.e. `ST_ClusterDBSCAN(ST_Transform(geom, <target_srid>), ...)`

Comment: May you live a happy and blessed life, thanks so much!